# Emulator visible but not in the list and not launch app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

For some reason not able to run app on emulator. I have tried `cold boot` , I have tried `wipe data`, I have tried `restart computer and android studio`. It looks like emulator launched but android studio not push app on it. When I click `play` button it starts avd manager but nothing happens
[image]